# Is there a function in joblib module similar to multiprocessing.current_process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, pid, joblib

I am trying to find the index of the worker which is currently running the function.

I have tried `os.getpid()`, but it gives the PID value. But I require the index of the worker i.e 1 for `Process 1` which is provided by `multiprocessing.current_process()`

```py
process = os.getpid() #gives 2435
id = multiprocessing.current_process()._identity #gives 1
```

I want the output [1-4] for a pool of 4 workers, but using a joblib module not `multiprocessing.current_process()`

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?